# Получить имя параметра с помощью функции

Tags: c#

#### Главное

Пишу библиотеку для консольных приложений и там есть функция которая выводит информацию о переменной. Только в нём одна проблема. Функция в начале должна выводить имя получаемого параметра а выводит имя переменной в функции.

---

#### Подробнее

*Library.cs*

```cs
using System;

namespace Library
{
    public class Print
    {
        ...
        public static void Information(object variable)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine($"Name - {nameof(variable)}"); //Вот тут проблема
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine($"Type - {variable.GetType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Hash Code - {variable.GetHashCode()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Value - {variable}");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```cs
using System;
using Library;

namespace Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float interval = 1.2f;
            Print.Information(interval);
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге получаем

[image]

То есть мне надо было вместо `Name - variable` - `Name - interval`.
*Собственно как это исправить?*

Comment: Я думаю никак. Методу вообще без разницы как называется переменная значение которой передано в метод. Этот вообще может быть не переменная, а поле класса или константа или выражение, да что угодно.

Comment: @tym32167, а вот тут Вы не совсем правы :) Это можно сделать и крайне просто

Comment: Не так давно завезли такую радость как `CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute`, который можно использовать в Вашем случае так: `static void Information(object variable, [CallerArgumentExpression("variable")]string expression = null)`. Компилятор самостоятельно передаст в `expression` то выражение, что Вы передали в качестве аргумента `variable` (а это может быть как переменная, так и целое выражение, как об этом и говорит @tym32167 :))

Comment: @Kir_Antipov упс :) это полезно знать, спасибо!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov спасибо, не знал, правда он появился только в .net core 3.0+

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, это да, но лично я уже давно все свои проекты перевёл на .NET Core 3.1 и .NET Standart 2.1 :) А для ранних версий Ваш ответ выглядит как наиболее простое решение, так что от меня Вам плюсик :)

Comment: @tym32167, всегда пожалуйста) Все `Caller...` атрибуты как раз и завозили для решения подобных задач, однако о них на удивление не так много людей знает, хотя там столько полезной информации для дебага: номер строки вызова функции, имя вызывающего метода и все такое ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov всё бы хорошо но только эта строка всегда пустая. http://prntscr.com/regcb4

Comment: @Арман, покажите, пожалуйста, вызов + уточните, какую версию компилятора Вы используете (нужен C# 8+)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov тут кажется до меня уже кто то задал этот вопрос. Вместо того чтобы завалить вас вопросами я лучше посмотрю как ответили на тот вопрос ։-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `Expression Trees`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test 
{
    public int z => 1;
}

class Program
{
    private static int private_field = 1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int xxx = 1;
        // обычная переменная
        Test(() => xxx); // Выведет xxx

        // аргументы "внешнего" метода
        Test(() => args); // Выведет args

        // член класса
        Test(() => private_field); // Выведет private_field

        // более сложная конструкция
        Test(() => new Test().z); // Выведет z
    }

    public static void Test<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body is MemberExpression member)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {member.Member.Name}"); // имя переменной
            Console.WriteLine($"Value: {expression.Compile()()}"); // значение
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Но все равно мне такой код кажется странным (т.к. у вас достаточно простой случай, просто одна переменная, имя которой известно на этапе компиляции), я бы все же использовал дополнительный параметр, например: `void Information(string name, object value)`, тогда можно было бы передавать его как `Information(nameof(interval), inverval)` или же это все обвернуть в class/struct, если таких значений несколько, то можно и словарь.

Comment: Оу, зачем так переусложнять?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если есть вариант получше - пишите. Я должен отметить один из ответов принятым, на данный момент этот единственный рабочий.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если есть проше возможность, напишите пожалуйста, интересно

Comment: @Арман, ответы уже давно не пишу принципиально, но в комментариях советы раздаю :) Смотрите мой комментарий под вопросом

Comment: Ответ ваш работает и довольно просто. Если в течении 24 часов ответов получше не будет я приму его. И всё же я отдам "голос за" за хороший ответ :-)